# access attribute from another class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm new in python and trying to solve this problem. I apologize if I am not really good in English. For this issue I shuoldn't change the argument of methods except dunder call. I only pasted the part of the code that I had a problem with. I am trying to use attribute of Passenger class(self.load_weight) in Trip class but I am get the error (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'Trip'`). How can I print the answer without any error?

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self, weight_capacity):
        self.weight_capacity = weight_capacity


class Trip:
    def __init__(self, train):
        self.train = self.train_validation(train)

    def train_validation(self, train):
        self.train = train
        return self.train

    def __call__(self):
        self.trip = Passenger(self)
        self.train.weight_capacity -= self.trip.load_weight
        return self.train.weight_capacity

class Passenger:

    def __init__(self , load_weight):
        self.load_weight = load_weight

    def attend_trip(self, trip):
        self.trip = trip
    
train = Train(34286)
trip = Trip(train)
passenger1 = Passenger(616)
print(trip())
```

Comment: are you sure that the problem is not caused by the double bracket in line 8 ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to feed a `Trip` object into `Passenger` here `self.trip = Passenger(self)`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that in the line `self.trip = Passenger(self)` use pass the Train object as an argument. Maybe it's an mistype, because in the Passenger class you named the variable `load_weight`. So I am assuming you should pass some kind of number instead of class object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working as expected is because inside the **call** dunder method of Trip class, you are instancing a new Passenger class instance, instead of using the passenger class instanced below;
plus the fact that you are creating the passenger instance itself after the Trip instance (the last 3 lines),

I've done a small refactor of you code, with the suggested modifications:

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self, weight_capacity):
        self.weight_capacity = weight_capacity


class Trip:
    def __init__(self, train):
        self.train = self.train_validation(train)
        
    def train_validation(self, train):
        self.train = train
        return self.train
    
    def __call__(self, passenger):
        self.trip = passenger
        self.train.weight_capacity -= self.trip.load_weight
        return self.train.weight_capacity


class Passenger:
    
    def __init__(self, load_weight):
        self.load_weight = load_weight
    
    def attend_trip(self, trip):
        self.trip = trip


train = Train(34286)
passenger1 = Passenger(616)
trip = Trip(train)
print(trip(passenger1))
```